# Performing translation of a 4x4 matrix by a 3 element vector

Tags: java, matrix

Lets say I have a `Matrix4f matrix`, populated with values that I'd like to translate by a point `Vec3 translation = new Vec3(2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);`

The formula below gives me unexpected results, how can I properly translate my matrix by the point? e.g

```
Matrix4f result = Utils.translate(matrix, translation);
```

This is my current translation code ..

```
public Matrix4f translate(Matrix4f matrix, Vec3 vector) {

    Matrix4f transform = new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, vector.x },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, vector.y },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, vector.z },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });

    return add(matrix, transform);
}

public Matrix4f add(Matrix4f matrixA, Matrix4f matrixB) {

    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();

    for (int a = 0; a < matrix.values.length; a++){
        matrix.values[a] = matrixA.values[a] + matrixB.values[a];
    }

    return matrix;
}

public void loadIdentity(Matrix4f matrix) {
    matrix.load(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });
}
```

This is definition of `Matrix4f` ..

```
public class Matrix4f {

    public float[] values;

    public Matrix4f() {
        this.values = new float[16];
        Utils.loadIdentity(this);
    }

    public Matrix4f(float[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Matrix4f(float[][] values) {
        load(values);
    }

    public void load(float[][] values) {
        this.values = new float[] {
            values[0][0], values[0][1], values[0][2], values[0][3],
            values[1][0], values[1][1], values[1][2], values[1][3],
            values[2][0], values[2][1], values[2][2], values[2][3],
            values[3][0], values[3][1], values[3][2], values[3][3]
        };
    }

    public float[] getValues() { 
    return this.values; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your matrix one-dimensional only? Also, what are your unexpected and expected results?

Comment: @GiantTree when i create the matrix, I load it with an identity matrix initially as a 2d array but its stored as 1d. i wouldn't expect storage mechanism to cause issues, right?

Comment: No it just looked odd to me to call a one-dimensional array *matrix*, which is not wrong, just odd because you load it with a 2-dimensional array. I will test your code in a second. Right now it looks OK to me.

Comment: This is what I've been told about my translation function .. "The translate() method is definitely not right. To translate something the matrix has to have 1.0 at position 3,3 and then you have to multiply it (either on the left or the right side) with the matrix you want to modify."

Comment: I see your issue: Adding two matrices is not the same as translating/moving them. Watch this short video to see how to translate a point/vector with a translation matrix: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs291/l-101410106/m-118429113. I am not very well at explaining how to do the maths but your translation function is not actually translating.

Comment: i watched the video but looks like a new vector is the result, but I need the translation to return a matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Matrix4f translate(Matrix4f matrix, Vec3 vector) {

    Matrix4f transform = new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 1, 0, 0, vector.x },
            new float[] { 0, 1, 0, vector.y },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 1, vector.z },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });

    return multiply(matrix, transform);
}

public Matrix4f multiply(Matrix4f matrixA, Matrix4f matrixB) {

    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f(new float[][] {
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[15])
            }
    });

    return matrix;
}
```